# Angular ng-view with sticky headers not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use the sticky headers directive from: http://ngmodules.org/modules/sticky-headers
but it doesn't seem to work with the combination of using ng-view.

When using the fsm directive as required, I'm getting an empty view:

```
angular.module('dashboard', ['fsm']).controller('installerController',
  [ '$scope', '$filter','$http','$log', '$location','$compile', 
    '$routeParams', 
    function($scope, $filter, $http, $log, $location, $compile, $routeParams)
```

When not including the fsm directive, everything works fine:

```
angular.module('dashboard').controller('installerController', 
[ '$scope', '$filter','$http','$log', '$location','$compile',
  '$routeParams', 
   function($scope, $filter, $http, $log, $location, $compile, $routeParams)
```

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the ng-view having an isolate scope.

From the docs

Example scenarios of multiple incompatible directives applied to the same element include:

Multiple directives requesting isolated scope.

Multiple directives publishing a controller under the same name.

Multiple directives declared with the transclusion option.

Multiple directives attempting to define a template or templateURL. It could also be that sticky headers uses transclusion as well.

Comment: Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the method `angular.module(string)` and `angular.module(string, array[])` is that the first one loads a specific module and the second one creates a new angular module

Make sure that you only create your module once

Comment: So what do you suggest instead of using:
angular.module('dashboard', ['fsm'])
??

Comment: Normally you have one call of `angular.module(string, array[])` where you create your module and declare the dependencies of your module. In the rest of your application you call `angular.module(string)` e.g. `angular.module("MyModule").controller(...`